# Private inner class synthesizes unexpected anonymous class

Tags: java, private, anonymous-class, language-implementation

When you compile a Java class with a private inner class, it appears that an anonymous class is automatically synthesized along with it for some reason. This class is sufficient to reproduce it:

```
public class SynthesizeAnonymous {
    public static void method() {
        new InnerClass();
    }

    private static class InnerClass {}
}
```

When compiled, this generates the expected `SynthesizeAnonymous.class` and `SynthesizeAnonymous$InnerClass.class` files, but it also generates a strange `SynthesizeAnonymous$1.class` file that corresponds to an anonymous subclass of `java.lang.Object` that was synthesized. If you look at the disassembly with `javap`, it appears the default constructor of `InnerClass` gains a hidden parameter of this anonymous type, and that `null` is passed to it when the `new InnerClass()` is called.

Why is this class created? It's created even if `InnerClass` isn't static, but it isn't created if `InnerClass` isn't private or no instance of `InnerClass` is ever created. Is it some form of access control? How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class is created in order to provide you with access to private constructor.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921025/eclipse-warning-about-synthetic-accessor-for-private-static-nested-classes-in-jav) for details.