# Do synthetic methods generated for private fields really incur performance penalty?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, java-synthetic-methods

In Eclipse, there is a optional warning when a private field is accessed from an inner class, saying that a synthetic accessor method will be generated and that performance may be improved by making the field package-private.

Does this synthetic method really incur performance penalty? I thought that accessors are generally inlined at runtime, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921025/eclipse-warning-about-synthetic-accessor-for-private-static-nested-classes-in-jav), in short - not much but it raises some interesting class design points